# ng-route got infinte when i use otherwise

Tags: angularjs

I have used the angular js with acl its working fine in other page but when i came on home page it will goes to infinite calling.

See below is my route code.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$q) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/error', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/front/donotaccess.html',
                    controller: 'DonotaccessController',
                    title: ' denied'
                }).
                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/front/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController',
                    title: 'Home',
                    resolve: {
                        'acl': function (AclService, $q) {
                            if (AclService.can('home')) {
                                // Has proper permissions
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                // Does not have permission
                                return $q.reject('Unauthorized');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).
        when('/search', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/front/searchresult.html',
                    controller: 'SearchController',
                    title: ' Search Results',
                    resolve: {
                        'acl': function (AclService, $q) {

                                return true;

                        }
                    }

                when('/cancel', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/front/paymentcancel.html',
                    controller: 'PaycancelController',
                    title: ' Status'
                }).otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/home'
                });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

When i refresh the page it will calling infinite can any one have idea please let me know..

Comment: Maybe an failed resolution of 'acl' fails the `when('/home')` resolution, leading you to `otherwise()` which redirects you to '/home' ?

Comment: @Aaron : No no it's a total different thing.

Comment: What kind of totally different thing if I may ask? I think we're a little light on details about what you describe as 'infinite calling'.

Comment: @Aaron : Acl is the access permission list right if user doesn't have permission then you can't access that module and here infinite calling means when i refresh the page it will  call (loading) infinite times i hope now you more clear

Comment: if i am removing otherwise case from my routing it will working fine but i need otherwise case just because of after user logged in it will redirect to home page using the same

Comment: If removing the otherwise fixes the problem, it seems obvious to me that the loop is otherwise -> when(home) -> otherwise. Maybe is there a $location call in your HomeController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might this trick can work for you .

You can create a service for a route like this.

```
when('/', {
    resolve: {redirect: 'defaultredirection'}
})
```

Now create a service like this.

```
app.service('defaultredirection', ['$window',  function($window) {        

    if($window.location.hostname == 'localhost'){
        //for local use.
        window.location.href = "/yourfolder/home"; 
    }else{
        //for live use
        window.location.href = "Your-URL-here/home"; 
    }  

}]);
```

Dont hesitate to let me know in-case it doesn't work.

Comment: What about .otherwise..?

Comment: You can add it if needed. else  do like  
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: 'home'
                });

Comment: I tried many times without otherwise but it will calling page infinite, in one of the case.

Comment: otherwise({ redirectTo: 'home' }) it should be their. Ok now working f9